# how to assign created_at only date string in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I Have a problem with the created_at and other carbon dates, when I do

```
return $return_items['created_date'] = $item->created_at;
```

It returns '2016-07-26 13:19:55'

but if I do

```
return $return_items;
```

it returns

```
"created_date": {
   "date": "2016-07-26 13:22:17.000000"
   "timezone_type": 3
   "timezone": "UTC"
}
```

How can I solve this, to only show the string date?

thanks

Comment: By default an Eloquent model's `created_at` property will return a string; with the above example, there is no reason you should have a Carbon class being returned. Check the logic in your code again, are you ever setting `$return_items["created_date"]` to a `Carbon\Carbon` class? If so, you can use `$return_items["created_date"] = $carbonClass->format("Y-m-d H:i:s);`

Comment: I just saving a new record $item = $user->Orders()->save($order)) and then assign some values in array like $return_items['price'] =$item->total; $return_item['created_date'] =  $item->created_at;

Answer (score 2):

```
$object->created_at->timestamp

$object->created_at->format('d M Y - H:i:s')
```

Comment: Please try to explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code,

```
$dateOnly = new DateTime($item->created_at);

echo $dateOnly ->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, display the date in the format you want and the `Hour`, `Minutes` and `seconds` :

```
{{ $user->created_at->format('d M Y - H:i:s') }}
```

Or only date :

```
{{ $user->created_at->format('d M Y') }}
```

More info, in the documentation [Laravel Date Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) and [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)